# Golang Regex to replace domain to proxy URL

Tags: html, regex, go

I want to replace all links of a webpage to a reverse proxy domain.

The rules are

```
https://test.com/xxx --> https_test_com.proxy.com/xxx
http://sub.test.com/xxx --> http_sub_test_com.proxy.com/xxx
```

How to achieve it by regex in golang?

The type of response body is `[]byte`, and character encoding of it is UTF-8.
I have tried in this way. But it cannot replace all the **dot** to **underscore** in the origin domain. The length of subdomain is variable, that means the number of **dot** can vary

```
respBytes := []byte(`_.Xc=function(a){var b=window.google&&window.google.logUrl?"":"https://www.google.com";b+="/gen_204?";b+=a.j(2040-b.length);
        <cite class="iUh30 Zu0yb tjvcx">https://cloud.google.com</cite></div><div class="eFM0qc"><a class="fl" href="https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:80SWJ_cSDhwJ:https://cloud.google.com/+&amp;cd=1&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:80SWJ_cSDhwJ:https://cloud.google.com/%2B%26cd%3D1%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dau&amp;ved=2ahUKEwia5ovYsv3xAhXS4jgGHad0BJYQIDAAegQIBRAG"><span>Cached</span></a></li><li class="action-menu-item OhScic zsYMMe" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?q=related:https://cloud.google.com/+google+cloud&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwia5ovYsv3xAhXS4jgGHad0BJYQHzAAegQIBRAH">
        `)
proxyURI := "proxy.com"
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(http[s]*):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.:]*)`)
content := re.ReplaceAll(respBytes, []byte("${1}_${2}."+proxyURI))
```

| origin | result | expect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://www.google.com | https_[www.google.com.test.com](http://www.google.com.test.com) | https_www_google_com.test.com |
| https://cloud.google.com | https_cloud.google.com.test.com | https_cloud_google_com.test.com |
| https://https://webcache.googleusercontent.com | https_cloud.google.com.test.com | https_webcache_googleusercontent_com.test.com |

Comment: Post what you've tried and the results you're getting. If you haven't already, check out the stdlib `regexp` package Replace functions: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAll .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```golang
func replaceAndPrint() {
    src := `
<a href="https://test.com/xxx">link 1</a>
<a href="https://test.com/yyy">link 2</a>
`
    r := regexp.MustCompile("\"https://(test\\.com.*)\"")
    result := r.ReplaceAllString(src, "http://sub.$1")
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Output:

```
<a href=http://sub.test.com/xxx>link 1</a>
<a href=http://sub.test.com/yyy>link 2</a>
```

Explanation:
`regexp.MustCompile`'s argument defines a capturing group (inside a pair of parentheses). The value of that capturing group is referenced by `$1` in the call to `r.ReplaceAllString`.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, misread the example.

Here's an updated version:

```golang
func replaceAndPrint2() {
    src := `
<a href="http://test.com/xxx">link 1</a>
<a href="https://sub1.sub2.test.com/yyy">link 2</a>
`
    r := regexp.MustCompile("(\\.|://)([^./]*)")
    replacer := strings.NewReplacer("://", "_", ".", "_")
    res := r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(src, func(g string) string {
        if g == ".com" {
            return replacer.Replace(g) + ".proxy.com"
        }
        return replacer.Replace(g)
    })
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="http_test_com.proxy.com/xxx">link 1</a>
<a href="https_sub1_sub2_test_com.proxy.com/yyy">link 2</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, the rule is not to replace the domain to its subdomain. 

Comment: Thanks, the `ReplaceAllFunc` and `ReplaceAllStringFunc` work well by matching the target, and **formatting with function** and replacing.